# I need to run a timer when I create a promise and when it times out, I want to reject /cancel the promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function returning  a promise object. When I call that function, I should start a timer. If the promise is resolved before the timer runs out, then fine. Else, the promise should be cancelled/rejected. How to do this?

```
var myPromise = somethingFunction();
timerService.startTimer();
myPromise.then((res)=>{
...
}).catch((err)=>{
});
```

//How to reject the promise when the timer runs out in this scenario?

Comment: And the question/problem is?

Comment: The request will time out on its own, without stopping the rest of the code.

Comment: Do you have some example of code to provide or something else? Context?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'one');
});

const promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'two');
  //Your custom function here....
});

Promise.race([promise1, promise2]).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  // Both resolve, but promise2 is faster
});
```

You can make use of Promise.race to do that. Promise.race takes in an array of promises and returns a promise if one of passed promises either resolves or rejects. Hope this helps!

In the example above, promise1 and promise2 are two promises. Of both, promise2 resolves faster as it has got a timeout of 100. Similarly, if you want to race between two promises, you can use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) to achieve this effect.

The following code randomly succeeds or fails:

```js
const timeout = (ms) => 
  new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject('timed out'), ms))

function foo() {
  const p = new Promise((resolve) => 
    setTimeout(() => resolve('success!'), Math.random()*200))
  return Promise.race([timeout(100), p])
}

foo()
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```